# Invalid resolution dpi. tesseract

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

[image]I have made some changes to an image such as histogram, dilation, gray scale, edge detection etc. to identify the number plate in an image.The below code is part of where i slice each charterer in the number plate and storing it in Mat. Now I'd like to use tesseract to identify each character. but instead tesseract throw this warning. " Warning. Invalid resolution 0 dpi. Using 70 instead." and OCR output is empty. Can anyone help me. 
Note: for now i'm doing only for one pic. just to check whether is it working or not.

```
if (!Plate.empty())
{

    imshow("Final Plate", Plate);
    waitKey();
    int x = OTSU(Plate);
    Mat BlurBinary = ConvertToBinary(Plate, x);
    Mat BinPlate = BlurBinary.clone();
    imshow("BinaryBlurImg", BlurBinary);
    waitKey();

    vector<vector<Point>>contours2;
    vector<Vec4i>hierachy2;
    findContours(BlurBinary, contours2, hierachy2, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));
    Mat dst1 = Mat::zeros(BlurBinary.size(), CV_8UC3);
    if (!contours1.empty()) {
        int i = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < contours2.size(); i++) {
            Scalar color((rand() & 255), (rand() & 255), (rand() & 255));
            drawContours(dst1, contours2, i, color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierachy2);

        }

    }

    Rect BlobRect2;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours2.size(); i++) {
        BlobRect2 = boundingRect(contours2[i]);
        if (BlobRect2.height < 10)
        {
            drawContours(BinPlate, contours2, i, black, CV_FILLED, 8, hierachy2);
        }
        else
        {
            Mat character;
            character = Plate(BlobRect2);
            imshow("character", character);
            waitKey();

            imwrite(format("C:/Users/Di/source/repos/LPRrecognition/Characters/Img%d.tif", i), character);

        }

    }
}
else {
    cout << "no plate sorry";
}

char *outText;

tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
// Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image1 = pixRead("C:\\Users\\Di\\source\\repos\\LPRrecognition\\Characters\\Img1.tif");

api->SetImage(image1);
// Get OCR result
outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);
cout << outText;

// Destroy used object and release memory
api->End();
delete[] outText;
pixDestroy(&image1);
```

Comment: Tesseract doesn't throw this warning. It is a not-so-silent warning that signals you "there is no DPI metadata in your image". This is okay and you can safely ignore this. For your original issue - you should post your preprocessed image, otherwise it is too hard to tell what's wrong

Comment: I have uploaded the original picture here. Could not ignore it. because OCR output is empty

Comment: In addition to the original image please post preprocessed image (the one you are feeding to tesseract). One suggestion would be to invert colors from black-white to white-black on the detected plates